# How can I get a string from a user and then dynamically allocate it?

Tags: c

I know I can do

```
char string[100];
gets(string);
```

But how can I dynamically allocate the memory towards that string, which might not necessarily be of 100 length?

Comment: The purpose of SO is to solve problems you have with existing code (or algorithms).  The purpose of the internet is to provide you with a place to search for such code.

Comment: Thing 1: just don't use `gets`.  It has no way of dealing with strings whose length you don't know in advance, it has no way of preventing overflow of the buffer you give it. Thing 2: you can either use `malloc` to create a buffer that you hope is big enough, then call `fgets`, then call `realloc` to shrink the buffer down to the size of the string you actually got.  Or, you can read the line a character at a time yourself, using `realloc` to keep growing a buffer bigger and bigger, as needed.  One way of doing that is shown in haccks's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `realloc` to get the string of unknown length. Read the entered string character by character until `'\n'` or `EOF` is found and use `realloc` each time to allocate memory for next character to be read.

```
char *read_string(void)
{
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    char *s = malloc(1);
    printf("Enter a string: \t"); // It can be of any length
    /* Read characters until found an EOF or newline character. */
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
    {
        s[i++] = c;
        s = realloc(s, i+1); // Add memory space for another character to be read.
    }
    s[i] = '\0';  // Nul terminate the string
    return s;
}
```

Comment: could be implemented with 'blocks' of N bytes to avoid `realloc` calls

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant; How?

Comment: For example `int block_size = 16;` and call realloc only if `i % block_size == 0`.

Comment: But dont you think the calls to realloc() are hefty?

Comment: @machine_1 : it's why i speak about blocks. If i remind, realloc and malloc use blocks internally but it's implementation-depending.

Comment: @machine_1; I do not care about *micro optimizations*. This reduces the productivity.

Comment: This function cannot tell an empty line from the end of file.